# How can I generate permutations of bit strings with repetition?

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

How can I write a function which has two parameters and it should generate combination of arbitrary range bits, for example: `function[n, k]`, with `n` being range, `k` being number of `1` digits. If I define `n = 4` and `k = 2`, the function should return the following set (in any order):

```
function[4, 2]
```

> ```
> {"1100", "1010", "1001", "0110", "0011", "0101"}
> ```

Answer (score 9):

You could e.g. do it like that:

```
f[n_, k_] := Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[1, k], ConstantArray[0, n - k]]]
```

and then format it to your liking

Comment: thank you very much. it is working

Comment: Just to make it more compact: `Permutations[PadLeft[ConstantArray[1, k], n]]`

Comment: Or `Permutations@UnitStep@Range[k-n, k-1]`

Comment: @ybeltukov While mine is a little improvement, yours deserves separate answer I think :)

Comment: @Kuba Now it grows up into the separate answer :)

Comment: @user2777109: I am not quite sure I understand what you mean. Maybe you want to look at `Inner` or `Outer` or `KroneckerProduct` or `Map` or `Apply`... also, if this is just a slight variation of this question, you might edit it (I rather wouldn't do so, as you have 3 answers here already to the existing question) or formulate a new question. The community can certainly help you better than I can do all alone.

Comment: @ Pinguin Dirk  ok. i asked it in a new questions.because. it is a diferent question

Comment: you can see in this title "how to permute bit strings and manipulate their elements"

Answer (score 6):

As I wrote in comment there are a more compact form of Pinguin Dirk answer:

```
f[n_, k_] := Permutations@UnitStep@Range[k-n, k-1]
```

However, `Permutations` is not a panacea. Let us consider straightforward approach

```
f2[n_, k_] := 
  Module[{res = ConstantArray[0, {Binomial[n, k], n}], pos = 0},
   With[{kk = Sequence @@ Table[Unique["k"], {k}]}, 
    With[{lim = Sequence @@ Transpose@{{kk}, Range[k, 1, -1], Prepend[Most@{kk} - 1, n]}},
      Do[res[[++pos, {kk}]] = 1;, lim]; res]]];
```

For small `k` it is much faster then `Permutations`!

```
f[500, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
f2[500, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 30.356745
>
> 0.797071

Comment: It's funny I should find this now, after your inefficient use of `Permutations` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32413/121); I see you are not unaware of the problem.  Why not use a method more like this one for that more recent question?  Anyway +1 on this. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The title of that question is "Replace For-loop with functional code" ;) So I suggested inefficient but in my opinion funny solution.

Comment: I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are dealing here with permutations with repetition, we can always compute the size of the set without actually generating the set:

```
{n, k} = {5, 2};
size = n!/(k! (n - k)!)
```

> ```
> 10
> ```

If `k = 2` is fixed, we can use the sequence of [`A018900`](http://oeis.org/A018900) from OIES to extract the first 10 elements and convert them to binaries:

```
seq = Take[WolframAlpha["A018900", {{"Continuation", 1}, "ComputableData"}], size]
IntegerDigits[#, k, n] & /@ seq
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 17, 18, 20, 24}
>
> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
>  {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
>  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

Comment: For the `size`, one could also use `Binomial[5,2]`

Comment: Yes, thank you @Pinguin, I sometimes forget how sophisticated _Mathematica_ is and tend to use more elementary maths :)

Answer (score 1):

`StringJoin@ReplacePart[ConstantArray["0",n],List/@#->"1"]&/@Subsets[Range@n,{k}]`