# how to permute bit strings and manipulate their elements

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, combinatorics

I want to write a `function(has 2 paremeter, n=range,k=number of 1 digits)` which finds all probable combinatorics of arbitrary bit strings and evaluate sum of tensor product and divide to `sqrt(n)` each elements.  if you look at the example you all understand easily. and sorry for my bad english .

```
function[3,1]
```

> ```
> (1\[CircleTimes]0\[CircleTimes]0)/Sqrt[3] + (0\[CircleTimes]1\
> \[CircleTimes]0)/Sqrt[3] + (0\[CircleTimes]0\[CircleTimes]1)/Sqrt[3]
> ```

another example

```
function[4,2]
```

> ```
> (1\[CircleTimes]1\[CircleTimes]0\[CircleTimes]0)/Sqrt[4] + (1\
> \[CircleTimes]0\[CircleTimes]1\[CircleTimes]0)/Sqrt[4] + (1\
> \[CircleTimes]0\[CircleTimes]0\[CircleTimes]1)/Sqrt[4] + (0\
> \[CircleTimes]1\[CircleTimes]1\[CircleTimes]0)/Sqrt[4] + (0\
> \[CircleTimes]1\[CircleTimes]0\[CircleTimes]1)/Sqrt[4] + (0\
> \[CircleTimes]0\[CircleTimes]1\[CircleTimes]1)/Sqrt[4]
> ```

Comment: You know how to get permutation from you previous quesiton what you should have mentioned. Now you can use for example this function `circle[x_List] := 1/Sqrt[Length@x] CircleDot @@ x` to map what you want. Try to use *Mathematica* notation here, here is no such thing as `sqrt(n)`, also, please pay attention to the way you format your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Using [ybeltukov's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov) function from [your previous quesiton](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32285/5478) and the one I suggested in comments you can create what you need:

```
 f[n_, k_] := Permutations@UnitStep@Range[k-n, k-1]

 circle[x_List] := 1/Sqrt[Length@x] CircleDot @@ x

 function[n_, k_]:= circle /@ f[n, k] // Total
```

[image]

Oh, I see, I used `CircleDot` instead of `CircleTimes`. Doesn't matter in fact, let me leave it as it is :)

Comment: @user2777109 so does it fit? I'm confused, you deleted the comment.

Comment: yes,thank you. lastly, if i want to merge two functions in one.like this. f[n_, k_] := Permutations@UnitStep@Range[k-n, k-1]
   circle[x_List] := 1/Sqrt[Binomial[n, k]] CircleTimes @@ x
function[n_, k_] := circle /@ f[n, k] // Total   there is a fail about Binomial[n,k]. how can i correct it?

Comment: i would write like this f[n_, k_] := Permutations@UnitStep@Range[k - n, k - 1]
 circle[x_List] := 1/Sqrt[Binomial[n, k]] CircleTimes @@ x
function[n_, k_] := circle /@ f[n, k] // Total  and there is an error, i think it is in Binomial[n,k]

Comment: @user2777109 `func[n_, k_] := Module[{perm, circle},
  perm = Permutations@UnitStep@Range[k - n, k - 1];
  circle[x_] := 1/Sqrt[Binomial[n, k]] CircleTimes @@ x;
  circle /@ perm // Total
  ]`

Comment: i really thank you very much. it was very important for me. you solved my problem

Comment: @user2777109 I'm glad it helps. Pay attention to the `Binomial` I'm not sure if it is consistend with previous version with `Length`. Good luck.