# Replace For-loop with functional code

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I am very new to *Mathematica*. I have code written using for loops. I want to rewrite it using [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html)/[`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) but I am not sure how to do it.

My code takes the set `A`, say

```
A = {{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}}
```

Then it insert a arbitrary character(say $a$) to every possible positions of given element in the set `A`.  So we get

> ```
> {{a, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, a, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, ..., 
>  {a, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, ..., {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, a}}
> ```

Then it inserts the same character again into resulting elements in following manner

> ```
> {{a, a, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {a, 1, a, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, 
>  {a, 1, 2, a, 3, 1, 2, 3}, ...., {1, 1 , 2, 2, 3, 3, a}}
> ```

This question come from Knot Theory-Chord Diagram

My program using for loops is follows.

```
A = {{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}};
kk = Length[A[[1]]]/2 + 1;

B = {};

For[m = 1, m < Length[A] + 1, m++,
  Diag1 = A[[m]];
  For[j = 1, j < (2*kk), j++,
    Diag2 = Insert[Diag1, "a", j]; 
    For[i = 1 + j, i < (2*kk) + 1, i++,
      Diag3 = Insert[Diag2, "a", i];
      B = AppendTo[B, Diag3];
    ];
  ];
];
```

This is what I tried to do with element 2.

```
f[x_] := Insert[A[[2]], "a", x];
B = Map[f, Range[7]]];
```

But I don't know how to put variable `A[[i]]` instead of `A[[2]]` and also how to insert other end of $a$ to this result using map.

Any comment really appreciated.

Comment: You might find `ReplaceList` useful: `ReplaceList[
 {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3},
 {x___, y___} :> {x, a, y}]`

Comment: Hi I modify my code to follows f[i_] := ReplaceList[A[[i]], {x___, y___} :> {x, a, y}];
B = Flatten[Map[f, Range[2]], 1];  Now I am not sure how to use ReplaceList to insert second end of "a". How do you use conditional if in ReplaceList? because say I have {1,a,2,3,1,2,3}. I don't want to insert second "a", in front of first "a". I want to insert second "a", all available position after first "a".

Comment: @ssch Darn, I just took time to build a solution using `ReplaceList` only to see you got there an hour before me.  I'm still going to post an answer since you did not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a rule/replacement based method using [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceList.html) and [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) that I think is elegant and easy to understand.

```
ReplaceList[{1, 2, 3}, {a___, b___} :> {a, x, b}]
```

> ```
> {{x, 1, 2, 3}, {1, x, 2, 3}, {1, 2, x, 3}, {1, 2, 3, x}}
> ```

```
ReplaceList[{1, 2, 3}, {a___, b___, c___} :> {a, x, b, x, c}]
```

> ```
> {{x, x, 1, 2, 3}, {x, 1, x, 2, 3}, {x, 1, 2, x, 3}, {x, 1, 2, 3, x}, {1, x, x, 2, 3},
>  {1, x, 2, x, 3}, {1, x, 2, 3, x}, {1, 2, x, x, 3}, {1, 2, x, 3, x}, {1, 2, 3, x, x}}
> ```

The only difficulty is extending this to an arbitrary number of insertions.  For that we need meta-programming, that is code that generates code:

```
sprinkle[v_List, x_, n_Integer?Positive] :=
  Table[Unique["a", Temporary], {n + 1}] /. syms_ :>
    ReplaceList[v, Pattern[#, ___] & /@ syms -> Riffle[syms, x]]
```

Now:

```
sprinkle[{1, 2, 3}, x, 4]
```

> ```
> {{x, x, x, x, 1, 2, 3}, {x, x, x, 1, x, 2, 3}, {x, x, x, 1, 2, x, 3}, ... }
> ```

Your original example may be had with:

```
A = {{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}};
Join @@ (sprinkle[#, a, 2] & /@ A)
```

You can leave off the `Join @@` if you want two sets of sublists; I could not tell form your question if that was desired.

Note: using a capital letter to start a user Symbol name is often a bad idea as these may conflict with internal functions – I preserved your original name for clarity alone.

Comment: Hi, Mr.Wizard Thanks for the post. This is great. Especially code for arbitrary number of insertions. Thank You.

Comment: @Vajira You're welcome.  Thanks for the Accept.  However, I recommend all users wait 24 hours before Accepting to give everyone around the world a chance to respond.  You may like another answer better if you give it time to happen. :-)

Comment: Now I'd like to ask past Rojo why he expected `ReplaceList` to return some redundant solutions

Comment: Ahh, it must be because he made a mistake when using `Subsets` (forgot to add 2) and yet trusted that more than `ReplaceList`. When lengths differed, he assumed. +1

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to first define a function that does all the insertions in a single list, starting from the nth position:

```
insert[z_, n_] := Insert[z, a, #] & /@ Drop[Range[Length[z]], n]
```

So for instance, with

```
x = {{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}};
```

we can apply `insert` to the first element of x by

```
insert[x[[1]], 0] to give

{{a, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, a, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, a, 3, 1, 2, 3}, 
 {1, 2, 3, a, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, a, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, a, 3}}
```

A second application of `insert` places a second `a` in each element:

```
insert[#, 1] & /@ insert[x[[1]], 0]

{{{a, a, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {a, 1, a, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {a, 1, 2, a, 3, 1, 2, 3}, 
  {a, 1, 2, 3, a, 1, 2, 3}, {a, 1, 2, 3, 1, a, 2, 3}, {a, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, a, 3}},...
```

as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be different

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3};
m = Length[list];
n = 2;

Module[{k = 0, b},
 Permutations[ConstantArray[a, n]~Join~ConstantArray[b, m]] /. 
  b :> list[[1 + Mod[k++, m]]]]
```

> ```
> {{a, a, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {a, 1, a, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, ..., {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, a, a}}
> ```

Comment: I am a fan of your methods but I can't support this one: it will scale very poorly with the length of `list`.  (ps you should include `b` in the `Module` declaration.)